# Object not persisting when saved in afterInsert event

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class like this:

```
 class Domain {
   String a
   int b
   String c
  ...


def afterInsert(){
       def anotherDomain = new AnotherDomain()
         anotherDomain.x=1
         anotherDomain.y=2

        if(anotherDomain.save()){
            println("OK")
         }else{
              println("ERROR")
          }

     }
  }
```

It prints "OK", I can even print the anotherDomain Object, and everything seems ok, no errors, nothing, but the anotherDomain Object doesn't persist in the database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot persist the domain to database unless you try to save `withNewSession`.

```
def beforeInsert(){
   def anotherDomain = new AnotherDomain()
     anotherDomain.x=1
     anotherDomain.y=2

    AnotherDomain.withNewSession{
       if(anotherDomain.save()){
           println("OK")
        }else{
             println("ERROR")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

All events are fired when domain object is `flushed` to database. Existing session is used for the flush. The same session cannot be used to handle `save()` on another domain. A new session has to used to handle the persistence of `AnotherDomain`.

**UPDATE**
Using `beforeInsert` event makes more sense than `afterInsert`. If `x` and `y` are dependent of any persisted value property of `Domain` they can very well be fetched from hibernate cache instead of going to db.

Comment: @luisZavaleta Rather I would suggest you to use `beforeInsert` event.

Comment: withNewSession worked, I had another unrelated error, but I haven't noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem here and just `.withNewSession` wasn't enough. I've putted  `.save(flush: true)` and everything is working fine.

```
def afterInsert() {

    AnotherDomain.withNewSession {
        new AnotherDomain(attribute1: value1, attribute2: value 2).save(flush: true)
    }
}
```